# Microsoft Azure - Multi region access blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

for software deployment reasons I want to set up a blob storage on Azure. I need to provide software packages not only for Europe, but for the US and parts of Asia as well. I do not want to set up 3 different blob storages (for each area), but one single blob storage, that can be accessed from all locations - ensuring low latency etc. Is this possible with Microsoft Azure?

Comment: for read access: yes (more or less). for write: nope

Comment: @silent Thank you for answering! I see you are a cloud solution architect for Microsoft, is there a way to get in contact with you for further information?

Comment: if you make your question a bit more detailed around what your scenario is, I can try to answer it.

Comment: @silent
So I work at a company that wants to change the way they approach software deployment. We use Ivanti for the package distribution and want to link Ivanti and Azure. We have offices in US, EU and ASIA, with EU as the main location. At first we thought we had to create 3 blob storages in the azure storage account, and then mirror them. But we want only ONE entry point for all configuration and stuff, so the task "where will I download the packages from" will be executed automatically. For example if the user is in US Azure will automatically use a server in the US for low latency.

Comment: @silent 
hope I could specify it good enough

Comment: I dont know Ivanti. But first quesiton would be: is latency in downloading some package (if that's what it is doing) really critical? I can't imagine it is a problem if the latency is 100 or even 200ms higher for some download

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228153/discussion-between-newbob-and-silent).

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- a)  have different regional storage accounts that you replicate into from one storage account. This way you have 1-write account but 3-read accounts. So yes, the people who need to read the data have different settings to configure
- b) you only use one storage account. but you put a [CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-a-storage-account-with-cdn) (content delivery network) in front of it. This will cache data close to the clients. only this connection URL will need to be specified for your clients. It is the same all around the globe

(Answer from silent copied from chat)